# rpm --upgrade not upgrading?

Tags: rpm

Can someone please help me understand the rpm command. From the rpm man pages:

```
rpm {-U|--upgrade} [install-options] PACKAGE_FILE ...

This upgrades or installs the package currently installed to a newer version.
This is the same as install, except all other version(s) of the package are
removed after the new package is installed.
```

My understanding is that if I indicate a `PACKAGE_FILE` that is an upgrade of something I already have installed, it will replace the files... upgrading the package.

Specifically I am trying to upgrade *VirtualBox* on a *Fedora 14* OS. I am running the following command:

```
rpm -Uvh VirtualBox-4.1-4.1.4_74291_fedora14-1.x86_64.rpm
```

and am getting (many) errors saying there is an older version of the file

```
... <similar output omitted>

file /bla/virtualbox/bla/powernotification-r0drv.c from install of
   VirtualBox-4.1-4.1.4_74291_fedora14-1.x86_64 conflicts with file from 
   package VirtualBox-4.0-4.0.12_72916_fedora14-1.x86_64

... </similar output omitted>
```

I am obviously not understanding something here. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Are you using the Fedora supplied RPM's or using something compiled by the VBox team? I'll leave this to a Fedora expert to answer but this usually happens when either the original rpm was installed multiple times and the installed file database has duplicate entries or the package isn't compiled correctly (sometimes a name mis-match) and doesn't understand that it is a new version of an existing package. You might need to either repair your RPM database, use a different package, or force the issue with `--replace-files` or uninstalling/installing.

Comment: I'll look into your suggestion... Thank you Caleb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-U` can only upgrade packages with the same name, and the two packages have different names. One is called `VirtualBox-4.0`, and the other is called `VirtualBox-4.1`.

```
VirtualBox-4.0-4.0.12_72916_fedora14-1       .x86_64
^name          ^version              ^release ^arch
```

Comment: How do you suggest upgrading that package? I may be wrong, but it seems pretty standard practice to name the packages according to their revision numbers as upgrades are released, so surely this is something that can be accommodated in some way

Comment: No. RPM is not meant to be used this way. You will need to remove the old package before you can install the new. You may be able to use `yum` to perform both in the same transaction, but this cannot be done with `rpm` alone.

Comment: I appreciate the information... I am still learning to "think in linux"... there is alot to learn :)

Comment: And third parties that pull this sort of stunt only make it harder.

Comment: Wrong. The package _name_ is VirtualBox, so there is no mismatch  there. The error messages are really informative, though: The installation would replace a file that is needed for some other package (or belongs to another package). Often happens when RPMs are carelessly slapped together by third parties.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, rpm is certainly able to update (replace old package with new). Has been from day one (or thereabouts).

Comment: @vonbrand: The package name is *not* "VirtualBox". Parse again, but from the right this time.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, you are absolutely right. Hastily built RPM, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

RPM is one package only, i.e. your command installs *just* the VirtualBox package. If the new version depends on updated versions of other stuff, the command will fail (obviously).

You might try "yum localinstall VirtualBox-..." (yum does first resolve dependencies, and gets whatever is needed). This might fail too, if the new version requires updates, and some existing stuff does depend on the updates (and no newer versions are available).

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of VirtualBox it is safe to erase and install again (e.g.):

```
# rpm --erase VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.28_117968_el6-1.i686
# rpm --install VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.18_124319_el6-1.i686.rpm
```

As mentioned above, this is caused by including the version number inside the package name, therefore RPM cannot figure out they are really the same package (possibly a bad packaging decision by Oracle).

```
# rpm -q -i VirtualBox
package VirtualBox is not installed
```

At first glance that seems confusing, but the version number is required because it's been made part of the package name.

```
# rpm -q -i VirtualBox-5.2
Name        : VirtualBox-5.2               Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 5.2.18_124319_el6                 Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Release     : 1                             Build Date: Tue 14 Aug 2018 01:15:57 PM GMT
Install Date: Sun 30 Sep 2018 04:45:04 AM GMT      Build Host: tinderlin4.de.oracle.com
Group       : Applications/System           Source RPM: VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.18_124319_el6-1.src.rpm
Size        : 176286250                        License: GPLv2
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Tue 14 Aug 2018 04:06:58 PM GMT, Key ID 54422a4b98ab5139
URL         : http://www.virtualbox.org/
Summary     : Oracle VM VirtualBox
Description :
VirtualBox is a powerful PC virtualization solution allowing
you to run a wide range of PC operating systems on your Linux
system. This includes Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, DOS, OpenBSD
and others. VirtualBox comes with a broad feature set and
excellent performance, making it the premier virtualization
software solution on the market.
```